# Bash - Add variable in associative array - bad substitution

Tags: bash, associative-array

Here is an expected behavior for associated array in bash

```
$ declare -A PC=( [Monitor]=Dell [CPU]=HP )
$ echo ${PC[CPU]}
HP
```

This gives me **HP** as output

Lets say I have these PC,Monitor amd CPU values stored in variable a , b and c. I am trying fetch the details now but I am getting "bad substitution" error when trying so.

```
$ a=PC; b=Dell; c=HP
$ echo ${$a[$b]}
bash: ${$a[$b]}: bad substitution


$ echo ${PC[$b]}
Dell
```

*${PC[$b]}*  however is returning expected output but not  *{$a[$b]}*

Not sure how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Syntax aside, neither `Dell` nor `HP` is a key in the associative array; they are *values* associated with the keys `Monitor` and `CPU`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called *indirection* - using one variable as the name of another variable.

In bash you do this for normal variables using the syntax `${!var}`, as in

```
a=5
b=a
echo ${!b} # 5
```

Unfortunately this won't work how you want for an array variable because the syntax `${!array[*]}` means something else (getting all keys from an associative array).

Instead, as suggested by a comment below, you can create a string for the entire reference and then use redirection on that:

```
lookup="$a[$b]"
echo ${!lookup} # will give Dell in your example
```

Comment: Indirection does work for arrays; you just need to construct an appropriate value consisting of the array name *and* the index. For example, `t="PC[Monitor]"; echo "${!t}"` will output `Dell`. Assuming `a=PC` and `b=Monitor`, `t="$a[$b]"` works as well.